# Formatting Numberfield and making it sortable in javafx Tableview

Tags: sorting, javafx, tableview, number-formatting

I have Column in tableview which is a Decimal. If I format it have thousand separator, the sorting happens as if it is a text. Appreciate if anyone can share an example code which keeps that column as number and sorts too as number.
Thanks
Jay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured, this is the way to solve the problem.

```
colName.setComparator(new Comparator<String>(){

 @Override 
 public int compare(String t, String t1) {
    try{
      DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###,##0.00");
       Double d1 =df.parse(t);                
       Double d2 = df.parse(t1);
      return Double.compare(d1,d2);
    }catch(ParseException p){
         p.printStackTrace();
    }
    return -1;

 }
```